# Is it possible to run a Windows .msi installer?

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine, msi

Is it possible to install a Windows program from an MSI installer so that the installed program can be run with the Wine program loader?

Answer (score 147):

Open the terminal, change directories with `cd` to the location of the .msi file, and install the .msi file with a command of the form `wine msiexec /i whatever-filename.msi`.

According to the official [WineHQ FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Running_.msi_files):

> MSI files cannot be run directly, you need to use the [msiexec](http://wiki.winehq.org/msiexec) program. msiexec is a tool for installing .msi packages. MSI files can be installed in Wine from the terminal like this:
>
> ```
> wine msiexec /i whatever-filename.msi
> ```
>
> Alternatively:
>
> ```
> wine start whatever-filename.msi
> ```
>
> That will then run the MSI program the same as if you had double-clicked it in Windows.

The first command can be changed if necessary to suit the circumstances. For example:

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix wine msiexec /i /path/to/filename.msi
```

or using wine64 instead of wine:

```
WINEPREFIX=/path/to/wineprefix wine64 msiexec /i /path/to/filename.msi
```

A WINE prefix is a folder that contains all of the WINE configurations as well as all of the Windows pieces that WINE uses for compatibility, including libraries and a registry.

If you want to uninstall the same .msi file later on run `wine msiexec /x whatever-filename.msi`

Comment: Ok, but how do I execute it after installation?

Comment: Yeah, just got the newgrounds flash player installed, but it hasn't appeared anywhere. I'm probably about to figure it out, but...