# Installing Hitfilm on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, video-editor

I've been using the Hitfilm Express software (http://www.hitfilm.com) to make videos on Windows for a while. The Hitfilm software installs from a .msi installer. I tried starting the msi according to the following question: [Is it possible to run a Windows .msi installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671277/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-msi-installer)

When I ran the installer, it initialized and showed a screen saying, "Hitfilm requires Windows 7 or higher." Is there a way to "trick" Hitfilm into thinking that I'm running Windows 7?

Comment: Do you trying DAVINCI RESOLVE, it seem quite a good alternative than workaround OS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal, and run "winecfg" to open the Wine options, then select Windows 7 from the version menu.

[image]