# how can i install .msi in ubuntu

Tags: wine, msi

[Is it possible to run a Windows .msi installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671277/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-msi-installer/991965?noredirect=1#comment1599910_991965)
i checked here and tried but it's not working.

```
pawan@pawan-HP-Pavilion-13-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ wine start ExpressoSetup3.msi 
err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeDirectory error reading registry key for installroot 
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions" returned 1603 ^C 
pawan@pawan-HP-Pavilion-13-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ wine msiexec /i ExpressoSetup3.msi 
err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeDirectory error reading registry key for installroot 
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions" returned 1603 
pawan@pawan-HP-Pavilion-13-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$
```

neither i get any MSI installer to install .msi

i can able to install .exe through wine but not .msi
i am using ubuntu 17.10 and just started linux.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: Does it need to be Espresso, which is a Windows editor? There are perfectly good Ubuntu-native editors available.

Answer (score 1):

If the Expresso 3 that you're talking about is the [regular expression development tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), I would suggest you to try some options that could replace it in Ubuntu:

- [A visual regular expression editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/kodos/)
- [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/wine.html)
- [Regexr](https://regexr.com)
- [Regex Pal](https://www.regexpal.com)
- [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com)
- [Rubular](http://rubular.com)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Let me add https://regex101.com to the list!