# Run Fortnite using Wine

Tags: wine

After following steps from the guide [Is it possible to run a Windows .msi installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671277/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-msi-installer), I’m not sure what I am supposed to do to get Fortnite up and running. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be impossible to get working through Wine:

"Game is unplayable because it relies on BattleEye anticheat which does not work through Wine."

[WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35818)

As far as it goes for Windows gaming: buy a license for Windows and set your system up as a dual boot for the best experience. A slightly less optimal method would be to install Fortnite in Windows in VirtualBox or VM Player in Ubuntu.